# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined --- How do I resolve this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, es6-promise

I am not sure why my function is giving me this error. In the function returning the value, I ensured there is a return statement on all levels. Could I have a second opinion as to why this error may be occurring? The service returns the data perfectly, the front end, however, is not seeing the return from my action.

**I tried other solutions with the same title, so hopefully, this is not a duplicate**

Front end:

```
componentDidMount() {       
    const { item } = this.props;
    this.props.getDetails(Number)
        .then((res) => {               
            this.setState({
                data: res.response.response.Results
            })
        });  
}
```

mapping:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getDetails(Number) {
            dispatch(getActions.getDetails(Number));
        }
    };
}
```

function retrieving:

```
function getDetails(Number) { 
   return (dispatch) => {
       dispatch({ type: policyConstants.ITEM_GETDETAIL_REQUEST });
    return Service.getDetails(Number)
        .then(
            response => {                   
                dispatch({ type: Constants.ITEM_GETDETAIL_SUCCESS });
                var pDetails = response.response.Results;
                return { pDetails };
            },
            error => {
                dispatch({ type: policyConstants.POLICY_GETDETAIL_FAILURE, error});                  
            }             
        );
    }
 }
```

Comment: Which line of code is throwing that error?

Comment: @MattU the .then line in the componentDidMount

Comment: In your mapping function you mispelled the getActions function as "detActions.getDetails"

Comment: The `getDetails` method of the object returned by `mapDispatchToProps()` does not `return` anything. The `getDetails` function in your last snippet does return an arrow function, the `Service.getDetails` is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.props.getDetails(Number)` in your `componentDidMount` is evaluated to `undefined` because `getDetails` in your `mapDispatchToProps` returns nothing.

Change like this :

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getDetails(Number) {
            return dispatch(getActions.getDetails(Number));
        }
    };
}
```